# Factor Clojure code setting many different fields in a Java object using a parameter map bound to a var or local

Tags: macros, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I would like to set a group of fields in a Java object from Clojure without using reflection at runtime.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579679/factor-clojure-code-setting-many-different-fields-in-a-java-object) solution (copied from one of the solutions) is close to what I am after:

```
(defmacro set-all! [obj m]
    `(do ~@(map (fn [e] `(set! (. ~obj ~(key e)) ~(val e))) m) ~obj))

(def a (java.awt.Point.))
(set-all! a {x 300 y 100})
```

This works fine but I want the macro to be able to process a map of fields and values passed in as a var or as a local binding (i.e. not passed directly to the macro as above). The fields should be represented as keywords so the following should work:

```
(def a (java.awt.Point.))
(def m {:x 300 :y 100})
(set-all! a m)
```

I can't figure out how to do this using set! and the special dot form within a macro (or any solution that works as above without using reflection at runtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I would do compile-time reflection coupled with polymorphism.

```
(defprotocol FieldSettable (set-field! [this k v]))

(defmacro extend-field-setter [klass] 
  (let [obj (with-meta (gensym "obj_") {:tag klass})
        fields (map #(symbol (.getName ^java.lang.reflect.Field %)) 
                    (-> klass str (java.lang.Class/forName) .getFields))
        setter (fn [fld] 
                 `(fn [~obj v#] (set! (. ~obj ~fld) v#) ~obj))] 
    `(let [m# ~(into {} (map (juxt keyword setter) fields))] 
       (extend ~klass 
         FieldSettable 
         {:set-field! (fn [~obj k# v#] ((m# k#) ~obj v#))}))))
```

This allows you to extend field setters per class.

```
(extend-field-setter java.awt.Point)
(extend-field-setter java.awt.Rectangle)
```

Now `set-field!` works on either and can be used with `reduce-kv` on a map.

```
(def pt (java.awt.Point.))
(def rect (java.awt.Rectangle.))

(def m {:x 1, :y 2})

(reduce-kv set-field! pt m) 
;=> #<Point java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2]>

(reduce-kv set-field! rect m) 
;=> #<Rectangle java.awt.Rectangle[x=1,y=2,width=0,height=0]>
```

Where in the `rect` example the `width` and `height` fields were left unaltered since not specified in the map.

Comment: In my case, I have already a Clojure map which has keywords corresponding to public non-static field names and values. I wanted a simple and fast way to use this map to set an object. The challenge around writing this macro seems to be around getting the structure right for the target keyword of the dot form. Try modifying the working example above to meet the case I am after to see what I mean. My answer below works but I feel it's a bit ugly.

Comment: The problem with determining the fields based on an input map is that these are run-time values. That forces you to use `eval` and invoke the compiler again at run-time. I prefer my approach of determining the set of possible fields at compile-time. I think one could easily take what I have written and modify to suit maps of subsets of those fields, hints above. Maybe I'll write it later.

Comment: Hi A Webb - I like your solution and it meets my requirements. Thanks! I agree with your comment. Eval is triggering an additional compile is ugly and probably the source of the performance problems. Doing it all in a macro is much better and I was struggling to figure out how. As a supplementary question, I am wondering what approach I could take if I wanted to avoid reflection to set the objects but still have the setters generated to work with arbitrary classes that are only known at runtime; I'm probably back to having to use eval with your macro. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just did a rewrite to do the close over generated map version I hinted at. This is more flexible and appears to be faster.

Comment: Fantastic! This is orders of magnitude faster than what I was using. Thanks

Comment: @optevo Re: thoughts? It is hard to imagine receiving a class a run-time that you didn't anticipate at compile time for which you still know some fields you want to set. It is more likely there is a set of classes with a common subset of fields and you don't know which of that set you might receive. In that case, define a protocol and use polymorphism.

Comment: @optevo Just altered the code to use polymorphism. Now all classes for which it has been extended respond to `set-field!` via polymorphism rather than having their own individually named setters. I rather like this now and might actually use it myself!

Comment: this is a fantastic answer and a great tutorial on macros. I was just looking to get rid of a whole bunch of code that sets values of java objects. a simple cut/paste of this answer gives me some serious code reduction with no loss of functionality. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this works. I'm not sure if it is faster than reflection and I'd like to see it done more elegantly if anyone has any suggestions.

```
(defmacro set-fn-2 [f]
    `(fn [o# v#] (set! (. o# ~f) v#)))

(defmacro set-fn-1 [f]
    `(list 'set-fn-2 (symbol ~f)))

(defn set-fn-0 [f]
    (eval (set-fn-1 (symbol (name f)))))

(def set-fn (memoize set-fn-0))

(def a (java.awt.Point.))

(def val-map {:x 1 :y 2})

(defn set-all! [o m]
    (doseq [k (keys m)] ((set-fn k) o (m k))))

(set-all! a val-map)

a
```